# C++ Allegro al_draw_textf ()

Tags: c++, allegro5

My question is related with Allegro 5 C++ . Here is some parts of my code which must draw text on the screen . I have done all the declarations and the error is  definitely in this part of the code.

So at first I have declared a global variable `ALLEGRO_FONT * font;`
I have called this function in main `al_init_font_addon();`

And here is another function which draws the text.

> ```
>     void draw (){
>         int score=0 ;
>         while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)){
>           al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb( 0 , 0 , 0));
>           al_init_ttf_addon();
>           font = al_load_font ("font.ttf" , 24 , NULL);
>           al_draw_textf(font , al_map_rgb(255 , 0 , 255) , 200 , 200 , ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE   , "SCORE: %d" , score );
>           al_flip_display();
>           score +=10;
>         }
>     }
> ```

The problem is that this app crashes on the 507 step of the while loop

Comment: Side note: there's really no need to use Windows-specific keyboard functions when Allegro provides cross platform routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing a new font each loop, while not unallocating the resource when you're done with it.

Instead call `al_init_ttf_addon` and `al_load_font` only once, before the loop, and use it in the loop. Remember to free the font when you're done with it. I actually recommend you call `al_init_ttf_addon` when you initialize the program instead, in other words in the `main` function before you enter the event loop.